# How to create a Bash script to execute a command until it success for max number of tries

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I’m trying to executing a bash script that tries to connect to a VP with a max of 3 retrie. I'm new to bash scripting so maybe there are several error, my code is the following:

```
current_server=$(nordvpn status | grep 'Current server:' | cut -c 17-| cut -d'.' -f1)
recommended_server=$(curl --silent 'https://nordvpn.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=servers_recommendations' | jq --raw-output '.[].hostname' | head -n 1| cut -d'.' -f1)
command = 'nordvpn c $recommended_server | grep "You are connected"'

if [[ $current_server == $recommended_server ]]; then
   echo "Uguali"
   echo "   Current: $current_server"
   echo "   Recommended: $recommended_server"
else
   echo "Diversi: "
   echo "   Current: $current_server"
   echo "   Recommended: $recommended_server"
   nordvpn d
   counter=0
   max_retry=3
   until $($command)
   do
      sleep 1
      [[ counter -eq $max_retry ]] && echo "Failed!" && exit 1
      echo "Retrying. Try #$counter"
      ((counter++))
   done
fi
```

thanx in advance!

Comment: Ciao, welcome on SuperUser. Feel you free to [edit] your post adding which is (are) the specific problem(s). I think it is that you should write `until ($command)` , without the  `$` before the `(...)`. Moreover you should initialize at 1 the counter since you do the check on the counter value before and increase its value after (else you will execute that part 4 times instead of 3)... Let me know if I guessed the problem. It should even work directly `until $command`.

Comment: thank you for your help! the problem is that the command in command var is not executed and the message "Retrying. Try #ciybter" never appears

Comment: You are welcome. Are you sure that `nordvpn` is not executed at all? Check if, from inside the script, you can reach `nordvpn`, (add a line with `type nordvpn; exit 0` or `which nordvpn ;exit 0` in your script to check it)... Try to execute a `$command` too. Did you try with `until $command` ? Some words more in the answer below...

Comment: Putting commands in variables doesn't really work (see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). Just put the command directly after the `until` instead of trying to store it in a variable first.

Comment: @GordonDavisson ... What did you find wrong in the [below answer](https://superuser.com/a/1518055/257269)?

Comment: @Hastur Your answer identifies one of the problems in the code (the spurious `$( )`), but it still won't work because you can't put a complex command in a variable. Again, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `until $command`

> **until** Test_COMMANDS; do Block_Of_COMMANDS; done

The `until` executes a Block_Of_COMMANDS *until* the Test_COMMANDS does not succeed.
Moreover, it expands and executes Test_COMMANDS each time.

The problem is that you wrote `$($command)` that is a proper command for `bash`,
even if not probably the one you had in mind:

- `until $($command)` executes `$command` then try to execute its output and to put it in a variable used for the test of `until`.
- **`until $command`** executes `$command` and use the exit code of the last command inside the `$command` as test for the loop.
- `until ($command)` do the same of the above case, but executing `$command` in a subshell (that takes the exit code from the final command executed inside)... same result.

---

From `help until`

> until: **until COMMANDS;** do COMMANDS; done
>       Execute commands as long as a test does not succeed.
>
> Expand and execute COMMANDS as long as the **final command** in the
>       'until' COMMANDS **has an exit status which is not zero.**

Ok not so clear. Better so

> until: **until Test_COMMANDS;** do Block_Of_COMMANDS; done